# Is there a single term for the *pair* (domain, codomain) of function $f$, or generally the (source, target) of morphism $f$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, terminology

This is just about finding concise terminology. So if $f:A \to B$, is there a *single generic name* for the pair (A,B)?

What about for the pair (domain, image)?

Comment: I would call this the "type signature" (of $f$), or perhaps just the "type". This is a reasonably common term, perhaps more popular in CS departments.

Comment: Could you give an example of a context in which you want to refer to these pairs?

Comment: @varkor as in "functors preserve morphism type", i.e .the type of the image is the image of the type: $Ff: FX \to FY$.

Comment: @DanielMroz Yes this sounds good to me. I wonder if the mathematicians have a term.

Comment: @varkor i.e. the image of $(s,t) \circ Ff$ where $s$ is the source function (which returns the domain of its morphism argument) and $t$ is the target function.

Comment: In practice, I think it is rare to refer to both domain and codomain at the same time for the same purpose. In your example, functors preserve *all* structure (domain, codomain, composition, identities), so it's not that domain and codomain specifically are paired here. Elsewhere, the domain and codomain play separate roles; I can't think of a situation in which a term for both at once would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only proposal suggested in the comments was "type signature" or type.